# TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I do a form Login to Study on React... and this error i can't resolve..

TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

My Code Error:

```
changeState(){

    const {isLogginActive} = this.state;
    if(isLogginActive) {
      this.rightSide.classList.remove("right");
      this.rightSide.classList.add("left");
    } else {
      this.rightSide.classList.remove("left");
      this.rightSide.classList.add("right");
    }
    this.setState((prevState)=> ({ isLogginActive: !prevState.isLogginActive }));
  }
```

Some one can help me... have a one solution for this ... doing in React.

Thanks.

Comment: The error is clear: `this.rightSide` is `undefined`. But without a [mcve] we can only guess _why_ that is the case.

Comment: provide the whole component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that `rightSide` is a property defined using the [createRef API](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs).

In that case, `classList` is only accessible through the `current` attribute of the `ref`.

```
this.rightSide.current.classList
```

As `createRef()` is asynchronous, it might return null if you are accessing it early, e.g. on the `componentDidMount` lifecycle.

Hence, it is always safer to add an if statement to check for `current`

```
changeState(){
  const {isLogginActive} = this.state;
  if (this.rightSide.current) {
    if(isLogginActive) {
      this.rightSide.current.classList.remove("right");
      this.rightSide.current.classList.add("left");
    } else {
      this.rightSide.current.classList.remove("left");
      this.rightSide.current.classList.add("right");
    }
    this.setState((prevState)=> ({ isLogginActive: !prevState.isLogginActive }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Bro... i resolved... its a stupid error. I forgot to put one Letter in uppercase haha 

const RightSide = props => {
  return <div className="right-side" ref={props.containerRef} onClick={props.onClick}> 
    <div className="inner-container">
      <div className="text">{props.current}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
}

return <div className="right-side" ref={props.containerRef} onClick={props.onClick}>  <<<< Here the "containerRef" was "containerref" ... My bad

Comment: @NinoPlays Why did you accept the answer when that isn't the solution to your problem (which seems to be a simple typo)? o.O